# View plot for Node in KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION

Tags: knime

I have been using KNIME 2.7.4 for running analysis algorithm. I have integrated KNIME with our existing application to run in BATCH mode using the below command.

```
<<KNIME_ROOT_PATH>>\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar -application org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION -reset -workflowFile=<<Workflow Archive>> -workflow.variable=<<parameter>>,<<value>>,<<DataType>
```

Knime provide different kinds of plot which I want to use. However I am running the workflow in batch mode. Is there any option in KNIME where I can specify the Node Id and "View" option as a parameter to KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION.

Would need suggestion or guidance to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted this question in KNIME forum and got the satisfactory answer mentioned below

As per concept of command line execution, this requirement does not fit in. Also there is now way for batch executor to open the view of specific plot node.

Hence there could be two solutions

**Solution 1**

Write the output of workflow in a file and use any charitng plugin to plot the graph and do the drilldown activity.

**Solution 2**

Use jFreeChart and write the image using ImageWriter node which can be displayed in any screen.